# How to emulate pressing "%" and ";" keys

Tags: c#, winapi

How to emulate pressing "%" and ";" keys

```
string a2 = ";:%1467";
byte[] bb = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(a2);

foreach (byte b in bb)
{
   InputWorkflow.SendKeyPress((ushort)b);
}
```

InputWorkflow:
http://pastebin.com/e9Hg24kD

Comment: How to print these two characters?
Need any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why your class isn't working

You are misusing the method described in that class; also  you have to pass keyboard scan code to the `InputWorkFlow.SendKeyPress(ushort keycode);`  method. It doesn't accept ascii bytes.

### What to use:

Use the [`SendKeys` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) it works the way you want:

```
string a2 = ";:%1467";
byte[] bb = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(a2);

foreach (byte b in bb)
{
   SendKeys.Send(b);
}
```

If you need to wait for each key to be processed then use SendWait instead of Send

```
foreach (byte b in bb)
{
   SendKeys.SendWait(b);
}
```

Starting from .NET 3.0 on Windows Vista onwards you need to add the following in your app.config:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="SendKeys" value="SendInput"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: read up on the quirks of SendWait the MSDN link describes (i linked it above) here it is again: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait.aspx